# Weird error on rails app, only on one browser, one url "Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error."

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, xml, nginx, ruby-on-rails-4

So here I am coding away happily, I check my browser to see some CSS changes ive made, and then I get this error, unlike any i've seen before:

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 45 at column 10: Opening and ending tag mismatch: link line 0 and head
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

1
```

No reference number, or any other info. It doesn't seem like a rails error and when checking my logs,

```
Started GET "/" for XXX.XXX.XXX.230 at 2013-11-04 15:15:35 +0000
  Processing by PagesController#show as HTML
    Parameters: {"id"=>"home"}
    [1m[35mPage Load (0.3ms)[0m  SELECT "pages".* FROM "pages" LIMIT 5
    [1m[36mPage Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "pages".* FROM "pages" WHERE "pages"."slug" = 'home' ORDER BY "pages"."id" ASC LIMIT 1[0m
    Rendered inline template within layouts/application (1.8ms)
    Rendered shared/_head.html.erb (5.8ms)
    Rendered shared/_header.html.haml (2.1ms)
    Rendered shared/_footer.html.haml (0.1ms)
  Completed 200 OK in 19ms (Views: 14.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
```

The error certainly doesn't look like a rails error, it just has a plain looking red box around it. Not sure if it could be an nginx error or something similar?

To make things even stranger, all other urls work except mydomain.com. In addition, mydomain.com works fine in firefox and my mobiles chrome browser as well as my chrome browser on my other pc. So perhaps some kind of cache/cookie issue? I am using devise for session control. Also it occurred whilst i was making changes to CSS, though that could be a coincidence.

I am yet to clear my cookies and see if that fixes it on chrome, just in case i need to reproduce the error.

**EDIT: after not running into this problem for a few weeks, again it popped up randomly, the exact same situation, this time with a slightly different error (perhaps because I have changed the code since?)**

`error on line 41 at column 8: Opening and ending tag mismatch: link line 0 and head`

The difficulty is in replicating it, because clearing the history remedies the issue and it could be weeks before I see it again...

W3C validation gives me the following error:
Line 14, Column 66: Bad value X-UA-Compatible for attribute http-equiv on element meta.

But even if I fix that, I cannot know with certainty that its what solved the problem..

`Line 14, Column 66: Bad value X-UA-Compatible for attribute http-equiv on element meta.
    <meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">`

Comment: Are you using google sitemap?

Comment: nope...did notice when searching for the error it could be xml related, as far as i know i havent touched any xml

Comment: Please paste relevant view code.

Comment: It seems a chrome standards thing, it is seen on non-rails sites. It just often occurs with sitemap generation.  Since it's telling you that you have a tag mismatch did you view the html?

Comment: I just checked on chrome on my other computer, working fine. Marek, if I knew what the relevant code was I would post it.

Comment: Clearing my history fixed it..sad to say it doesn't shed much light on the problem

Comment: I found a same page issue here: http://longomatch.org/forum/extern.php?action=feed&tid=373&type=rss
But opening the source of this page locally in a browser works fine.

Seems like your document structure is messed up somewhere.. worth a check , if you could view the source of the page and manually validate.  - Just my 2 Cents.

Comment: It sounds almost like your browser is treating the document as XML. Is your server misconfigured?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's related to a chrome plugin you are using especially if it is only happening in one browser. I would try disabling all plugins and try again.

Answer (score 0):

This is an error from your browser telling you the XML document it's loading isn't valid XML. This raises the following questions:

- Are you intentionally serving your content as XHTML? I wouldn't recommend this, and this kind of problem is one of the reasons.
- Are you accidentally serving your content as XHTML or some other XML? You can check the content type of the document returned (in your browser's developer tools). "text/html" is HTML, and what you want.
- Are you occasionally serving your content as XML? Perhaps you have Atom or RSS feeds for the same actions, and you use page caching, and your page caching isn't taking into account the format requested, so sometimes if Atom or RSS is the first request then things get confused? Again here, you should check the the content type if the error reoccurs.